# How can I get selected value from ngSelected, if i'm using compareWith?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-ngselect

I have a complex form with a dynamic length array of group of fields.
Each line has a ngSelect. The other fields of the line uses some information of the selected data in order to show different options or making calculations in different ways.
When submitting the form I save only some fields of the selected object in the ngSelect. So when loading the form with saved data, I use a `compareWith` function to show the correct item in the ngSelect.

Everything works fine, except I cannot get the whole data of the selected object so I can make the calculations in the other fields. With `field.value` I can get only the limited data I use to tell ngSelect what item is selected, not the item is selected.

I made a small [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngselect-comparewith?file=src%2Fbindings-default-example.component.ts).
Here you can see that if you select 'Flip flops' from the list, it shows all the fields of the selected object. But if you click on the button 'Choose flip flops', it shows only 'value' and 'label'. Is there some workaround to get all the data so I can make the calculations?

In my real app the list of options `defaultBindingsList` is an Observable I get from another function with parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If i understand that You want get all data i test You example and this is result

```
**name for ng-select**

<ng-select #select [items]="defaultBindingsList"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
           [compareWith]="compareFn"
           **in change method add name**
           (change)="onChange(select)">
</ng-select>
**in on click add the name**
<button (click)="onClick(select)">choose flip flops</button>
```

and method for get whole data is this

```
 onClick(select) {
    this.selectedItem = select;
  }
```

[image: stac]

I hope that is what You looking for.

Another way for select item with click and get all data is next

```
onClick() {
    const k = this.defaultBindingsList.filter(d => d.value == 3)
    this.selectedItem = k
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't get your first example. I updated stackblitz with that code, but it gets an error.
In my real app the form is more complicated and I'm using an observable for the options, and I'm avoiding to subscribe  in order to use `.filter()`. But maybe is the only way to get that data. I was thinking it's possible to get that data somehow from the ngSelect field

Comment: Personally to have access to all the data of a record, first I put it in a list or using MatTableDataSource and from there I do what I want and if you use subscriber inside the function the variable you can also filter in the same way, Good luck

Answer (score 1):

On your `onClick()` method you manually add only the `value` and `label` attributes of your `flip flops` item (`this.selectedItem = { value: 3, label: "flip flops" };`). If you want `flip flops`, you can get all the object like this :

```
onClick(){
  this.selectedItem = this.defaultBindingsList.find(item => item.label == "flip flops");
}
```

Comment: Yes. I thought something like that but with `item.value`.. The thing is that in my real app the options list is an observable that is got depending on other parameters. And the user can add more lines, each of them with an ngSelect.
I could subscribe to the list of options, and use `options.find()` but I'm wondering if there is something simpler.